# Unable to resolve service for type when using my repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

When I try and access my repository, I receive an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'software.Notes.Repositories.NoteRepository' while attempting to activate 'software.Notes.Http.Handlers.ShowNote'.

So, I have a simple SoftwareContext:

```
public class SoftwareContext : DbContext
{
    public SoftwareContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        { }
        
        public DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Note> Note { get; set; }
    }
}
```

which is instantiated in my startup.cs file:

```
services.AddDbContext<SoftwareContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Now, I have a simple request handler to show a note:

```
[ApiController]
public class ShowNote : Controller
{
    private readonly NoteRepository _note;

    public ShowNote(NoteRepository note)
    {
        _note = note;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("note/show/{id}")]
    public IActionResult init(int id)
    {
        Note note = _note.Find(id);

        if (note != null) {
            return Ok(note);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

And inside my repository I have the following:

```
public abstract class NoteRepository : INoteRepository
{
    private readonly SoftwareContext _context;

    protected NoteRepository(SoftwareContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    public Note Create(Note note)
    {
        var add = _context.Note.Add(note);

        return note;
    }

    public Note Find(int id)
    {
        return _context.Note.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the Context be injected via the constructor of my repository like I am currently doing? Can someone explain why this isn't working, and what the correct way to do it for it to work would be?

Full exception log:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'software.Notes.Repositories.NoteRepository' while attempting to activate 'software.Notes.Http.Handlers.ShowNote'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: At a guess: `SoftwareContext` is being registered as `DbContext` only.

Comment: Have you registered `NoteRepository` in `startup.cs`?

Comment: The error isn't about `SoftwareContext` it is about injecting `NoteRepository` into `ShowNote` constructor.

Comment: what dependency injection framework did you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to add your NoteRepository inside the .NET Core’s IOC container. There are three ways to do that:
in the startup.cs class add

```
services.AddScoped<INoteRepository, NoteRepository>();
```

which will create instance of NoteRepository class once per request

```
services.AddSingleton <INoteRepository, NoteRepository>();
```

which mean instance of your NoteRepository class will be shared across requests

```
services.AddTransient <INoteRepository, NoteRepository>();
```

which will create the instance each time application request it.

then you can inject the dependency through constructor of your controller

```
 [ApiController]
 public class ShowNote : Controller
 {
  private readonly INoteRepository _note;
  public ShowNote(INoteRepository note)
    {
        _note = note;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to pass the context to the dbcontextoptions in the constructor? So try change this:

```
public SoftwareContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    { }
```

to this:

```
public SoftwareContext(DbContextOptions<SoftwareContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
```